# Is an atomic object unsafe in any context where a plain object is safe?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, race-condition, memory-model, stdatomic

My question is simple: is there any parallel algorithm where using an object of a trivial type `T` is legal and safe (well defined, guaranteed to work) and using instead an `std::atomic<T>` object leads to unspecified or undefined behavior? **In other words, it is possible for a non atomic type to provide stronger guarantees than an atomic type?**

Are all the guarantees of memory visibility valid for atomic object when they are valid for regular objects?

[That would mean that a compiler could treat (relaxed) atomic and non atomic operations the same, simplifying intermediate representation.]

If yes, **is that formally provable?**

Of course types `T` such that `std::atomic<T>` isn't a valid specialization of `std::atomic` don't count.

Comment: No, there is no such context.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is special (packed bit-array), `vector<atomic<bool>>` isn't.  But `vector<atomic<T>>` is barely usable (not copyable so only fixed-size construction and `[]` access work, not push_back), and I don't think this is the kind of think you had in mind.  (You could imagine breaking it by hard-coding some assumptions about the object representation or sizes, maybe, if `.data()` is even accessible for `vector<bool>`).

Comment: @PeterCordes Not at all what I what wondering about, but still worthy of being mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

No scenario in which a non-atomic value has a stronger guarantee when compared to it's `atomic` equivalent.

The only bad pattern I can think of, is when a developer makes a mistake of assuming that if all members of a data structure are individually thread safe, then the entire data structure is assumed to be thread safe. This would not be a correct assumption.

Consider the following hypothetical:

```
class Volume
{
    atomic<int> _width;
    atomic<int> _height;
    atomic<int> _depth;
public:
   int computeValue() {return (_width*_height*_depth);}
   void SetInternals(int w, int h, int d) {_height=h;_width=w;_depth=d;}
};
```

Where thread 1 does this:

```
f->SetInternals(42, 100, 200);
```

And thread 2 does this at the same time.

```
int something_important = f->computeValue();
```

You can see that the value returned by `computeValue` may be corrupted if both threads execute at the same time.

You can achieve the desired thread safe behavior with a mutex and lock combo instead of atomics:

```
class Volume
{
    int _width;
    int _height;
    int _depth;
    mutex _mutex;
public:
   int computeValue() {
        lock_guard<mutex> lck(_mutex);
        int result = _width*_height*_depth;
        return result;
   }
   void SetInternals(int w, int h, int d) {
      lock_guard<mutex> lck(_mutex);
      _height=h;_width=w;_depth=d;
   }
};
```

Comment: Of course, if you use the mutex *and* the atomics, it's still safe. So it's not quite the same thing as the OP asked, where if you just took out the atomics, it suddenly becomes safer.